# passing multiple ids into url Django

Tags: python, html, django

Hi I am trying to send the user back to the  html file however when I used the following code in my view function:

```
def delete_topic(request, topic_id):
    """ Delete Topic """
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    topic.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blogging_logs:topics'))
```

its giving me a NoReverseMatch error and I can't seem to figure out why. I notice that my view function for topics requires category_id but I am not sure how to pass multiple ids.

[image]

here is my **topics view**

```
def topics(request, category_id):
    """Show all topics for a single category"""
    category = Category.objects.get(id=category_id)  # get category that was requested
    topics = category.topic_set.all()  # get all topics associated with category that was requested
    context = {'category': category, 'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'blogging_logs/category.html', context)
```

Here is the html page for where the delete_topics def is being used.
**topic.html**

```
{% block content %}
<h3>{{ topic }}</h3>
  {% for entry in entries %}
      <p>{{ entry.text|linebreaks }}</p>
    {% empty %}
      <li>No entry entered yet!</li>
    {% endfor %}

    <a href="{% url 'blogging_logs:entry' topic.id %}"> Add entry </a>
    <a href="{% url 'blogging_logs:delete_topic' topic.id %}">Delete Topic</a>
{% endblock content %}
```

I tried to add a second id (**category.id**) to the url (**delete_topic**) in topic.html but it gave me an error. I am assuming my error is that its not getting the category id needed to send the user back to the topics page.

Comment: can you show your urls.py file for this views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need multiple IDs, only the category ID.

Second, you need to add it in the Python code rather than in the template:

```
 return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blogging_logs:topics', args=(topic.category_id)))
```